Remote debug to Entra-joined pc
I have a virtual pc on Hyper-V joined to Entra ID.  The Visual Studio remote tools are running but I can't connect to it from Visual Studio running on my development machine.  I get a credential prompt but entering the correct username and password doesn't give me access - it just prompts again.  The username is in UPN format and can be used to log on interactively without a problem.
I'm using VS 2022 and the Entra PC is Windows 10
I just get authentication failed.  I ran the remote debugger configuration wizard and it added the firewall exception

Sorted it myself.  Use a local admin account on the machine and also run the remote debugger service under that same account (not LocalService).
